# (bash) how to add some iteraion to filename

Tags: linux, bash, shell, variables

I have the script that creates some .html and .txt files every day. But now it is only one file html and txt with changed content, I need every day a new html&txt file with date oof creation in the file name like : `index_22-05-2013.html` , i have these variables in shell script:

```
DESTINATION_HTML="./daily/html/index_$(date +"%F").html"
DESTINATION_TXT="./daily/txt/index_$(date +"%F").txt"
```

and a line in shell script that running one python script and creates html file

```
python `somescript.py` -m ${FILELIST[0]} ${FILELIST[1]} > $DESTINATION_HTML
```

and i`m getting this file created:

```
index_$(date +"%F").html
```

what i must to do to get this file name : `index_22-05-2013.html`

Comment: works for me `bash-3.2$ echo "./daily/html/index_$(date +"%F").html"` 
`./daily/html/index_2013-07-31.html` -- please echo out the variable and check what it contains. what shell are you using exactly?

Comment: As an aside, the quotes around `%F` are unnecessary, as are the backticks around `somescript.py`.

Comment: Are you actually using single quotes when defining `DESTINATION_HTML`? That would cause the command substitution to be treated literally instead.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I am not following you, but since

```
echo "index_$(date +%F).html"
```

outputs **index_2013-08-20.html** instead of **index_22-05-2013.html** which is what you need, you probably want to use this command instead:

```
echo "index_$(date +%d-%m-%Y).html"
```

Hope it helps! :)